# How to update Trust Framework Policy using Microsoft Graph Beta?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, beta, identity-experience-framework

From this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframework-put-trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta) we see it's possible to update a Trust Framework Policy. Anyways I couldn't find a way of doing the same using [Microsoft Graph Client Beta SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta).

Right now I have this code which works, where **policyId** = `B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions`:

```
var policy = await graphServiceClient
                .TrustFramework.Policies[policyId]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

Then I'd like to update the content of this policy and call:

```
await graphServiceClient
          .TrustFramework.Policies[policyId]
          .Request()
          .UpdateAsync(policy);
```

However I can't see any property in the policy object returned from Microsoft Graph in which I can pass the modified policy XML content.

[image]

My question is: can it be done using Microsoft Graph Beta client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TrustFramework policies` in Microsoft Graph are available as a blob in the api. Please note the $value parameter in the `get` and `put` apis. So the usual way of accessing data will not work. A sample code is given below for how to read and write the policies

```
        var requestBuilder = graphServiceClient.TrustFramework.Policies[policyId];
            var url = requestBuilder.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("$value");
            var builder = new TrustFrameworkPolicyContentRequestBuilder(url, graphServiceClient);

        // Read a policy
        using (var stream = await builder.Request().GetAsync())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var policyContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("Policy Read " +  policyContent);
        }

        string path = @"<FilePath>";

        // Write a policy. lets say path has the to be uploaded file content
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        using (var stream = await builder.Request().PutAsync(sr.BaseStream))
        using (StreamReader osr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updated policy content" + osr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Comment: Hey Abhishek... thanks for the answer! I didn't play with this code because I resorted to calling the endpoints directly instead of using the client SDK. This for sure will help in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you advise on how to create a new policy? For some reason I;m unable to create a policy and content in one reauest. Creating a policy first and subsequently writeing the xml content in a second step also does not work.

Comment: @ArievanSomeren what error are you seeing?

Comment: @AbhisekAgrawal : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/734. I think it is a bug in the beta library.